# Chakra overriding Arch?/ Is this possible?

Tags: arch-linux

My Arch installation didn't go well so can I install Chakra project to override the Arch installation?? By just installing Chakra in the same partition with Arch? Is it possible?

How hard is the Chakra installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never installed chakra, my suggestion, install it on the same partition, but make sure that you tell chakra to *format the partition*, lose all data, etc.